# Mathematical (and any other related e. g. statistical/economic...) Notation System

Tags: reference-request, notation

I would like to ask where I could find really extensive source (websites, books, whatever you are aware of) for studying purposes in terms of mathematical notations. This is really a must for me, because whenever I try to study some kind of a problem I encounter mathematical notations which should help me to understand the concept that is being explained, but in the end I do not understand what is being explained but I am only intimidated by the notations.

Comment: You could try http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mccp-matthews-symbols.pdf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols as a start

Comment: If notations are very standardized, you will find them introduced in textbooks (calculus, algebra, etc.), and since you will find the same notations used repeatedly, it is ordinarily not difficult to keep them in mind.  If notations are not well standardized, the authors of books and papers should define them for the reader there in an early section or they are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

CW Answer to push it out of unanswered queue:

You could try [mathcentre.ac.uk](http://mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mccp-matthews-symbols.pdf) and [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)